# How To Solve The Congruence $n\equiv1\pmod{\tau(n)}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

This problem raised in my mind while solving an elementary number theory problem.

**Problem statement:**
For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $\tau(n)$ notes the number of positive divisors of $n$ including $1$ and $n$.  Find all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that, $n\equiv1 \pmod{\tau(n)}$.

**Partial progress:** We know by **Fermat's little theorem**, $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$, where $a$ is a natural number, $p$ is a prime and $\mathrm{gcd}(a,p)=1$. If we take $n=p^{q-1}$ for two different primes $p,q$, then $\tau(n)=\tau(p^{q-1})=(q-1+1)=q$. So by **Fermat's little theorem** we get that $n\equiv1\pmod{\tau(n)}$. In fact let $n=p_1^{(q_1-1)}p_2^{(q_2-1)}\ldots p_k^{(q_k-1)}$, where $p_i$'s and $q_i$'s are distinct primes and $\mathrm{gcd}(p_i,q_i)=1$ $\forall\;i\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. Then $p_i^{(q_i-1)}\equiv\pmod{q_i}$ as before for all $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. Now $\tau(n)=(q_1-1+1)(q_2-1+1)\ldots(q_k-1+1)=q_1q_2\ldots q_k$. Since $\mathrm{gcd}(q_i,q_j)=1$ $\forall\;1\leq i\neq j\leq k$, therefore, $n=p_1^{(q_1-1)}p_2^{(q_2-1)}\ldots p_k^{(q_k-1)}\equiv1\pmod{q_1q_2\ldots q_k}$ or $n\equiv1\pmod{\tau(n)}$.

**Main question:** Are these numbers are the only solutions? If not, what is the set of solutions to the congruence $n\equiv1\pmod{\tau(n)}$?. Can we find the whole set parametrically?

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: It is most likely the case that you cannot parametrically find ALL solutions. You can make some manipulations to find some solutions. For example, $p^{p-2}$ and $p^{2p-3}$ work  by Fermat's Little Theorem for odd primes $p$. You have other trivial solutions like $p$ and $p^2$ where $p>3$ is prime. But the problem is almost impossible to FULLY SOLVE (in the sense, characterizing all solutions) since we could find many pathological solutions. I might be wrong, but it is most likely the case that due to this reason, there might not exist a characterization for all solutions.

Comment: As @Haran mentioned, it may be impossible to find a general form of such number; e.g. 33 satifies your congruence even though there doesn't seem to be anything special about it. You may try to restrict the class of solution though; for instance if $n$ is even and satisfies the congruence, then it must necessarily be a square (otherwise the number of divisors is even).

Comment: Suppose for all $ i=1,2,...,r $,  $ (a_i-1)|\phi(\prod {a_i} =m) $. Now for $(p_i,m)=1$, ${p_i}^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 (\text{mod} m)$. You may find some $r_i|\phi (m)$ such that ${p_i}^{r_i} \equiv 1 (\text{mod} m)$ . If possible let those $r_i=a_i-1$. Then you are done.

Comment: A somewhat weaker task is solvable : Given the number of divisors $n$ must have, we can find all numbers satisfying the congruence in the sense that we can detemine all configurations with the exponents together with the residues of the prime factors modulo the number of divisors. But a classification of all solutions seems impossible also to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Lehmer's%20totient%20problem,This%20is%20an%20unsolved%20problem.&text=Lehmer%20conjectured%20in%201932%20that,composite%20numbers%20with%20this%20property.

Comment: 297 and 513 do not seem to be of the said form.